# Passing Int type value via query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, query-string

I am able to successfully pass string values, but having trouble passing integer value via Query String.

If I only pass string objects the URL looks like

`www.website.com/mypage?ProductName=TestName&MahName=TestName` (Correct)

However, if I pass `Id (int)` along with the query string the URL looks like

`www.website.com/mypage/1?ProductName=TestName&MahName=TestName` (Incorrect)

However, I would like it to be

```
www.website.com/mypage?Id=1&ProductName=TestName&MahName=TestName
```

Model

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SecureMedi.Models
{
    public class CustomProductData
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string MahName { get; set; }

        public static CustomProductData FromSqlReader(SqlDataReader rdr)
        {
            return new CustomProductData
            {
                Id = (int)rdr["id"],
                ProductName = rdr["product_name"].ToString(),
                MahName = rdr["mah_name"].ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CustomProductData(int Id, string ProductName, string MahName) {
    var model = new CustomProductData() {
        Id = Id,
        ProductName = ProductName,
        MahName = MahName
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomProductData(CustomProductData cp) {
    try {
        using(ISecureMediDatabase db = new SecureMediDatabase(this)) {
            CustomProductDataDAL cpd = new CustomProductDataDAL(db);
            cpd.Edit(cp);
            return RedirectToAction("LoadCustomProductData");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        return View(cp);
    }
}
```

DAL

```
public void Edit(CustomProductData cp) {
    try {
        string sql = "UPDATE table_name SET product_name = @ProductName, mah_name = @MahName WHERE id = @Id";

        if (cp.HasDetails()) {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", cp.Id));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", cp.ProductName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MahName", cp.MahName));
                PrepareCommand(cmd);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    } catch {
        closeConnection();
        throw;
    }
}
```

cshtml

Anchor link to pass the query string values to the edit page (which take the values from the QueryString)

```
<td class="text-secondary">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CustomProductData", "Home", new { Id = @item.Id, ProductName = @item.ProductName, MahName = @item.MahName }, new { @class = "text-info" })</td>
```

Comment: Please show us your route definitions.

Comment: You have parameter named Id in your route configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the variable name `Id` was occupied in the routing and thus changing the variable name `Id` to `RecordId` solved the issue.